# Set Android Dialog location

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, location, positioning

I would like my Android Dialogs and/or Alerts to be aligned at the very top of the screen sometimes and not simply in the center. Is this possible? How about giving exact x-y coordinates, is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out:

[Positioning a dialog on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518995/positioning-a-dialog-on-screen)

[Transparent Dialog Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314230/transparent-dialog-alignment)

This one should give you an idea:

[How to change the positioning of a progress dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392256/how-to-change-the-positioning-of-a-progress-dialog)